# Submit form without refresh after selection from dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to set up a form so that it submits (without refreshing the page) when a selection is made from a dropdown menu. I currently have it set to submit when the dropdown is select, but it refreshes the page.

My code for the form is,

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select name="day" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option>Please select a date</option>
<option value="Mon"><?php echo $monday; ?></option>
<option value="Tue"><?php echo $tuesday; ?></option>
<option value="Wed"><?php echo $wednesday; ?></option>
<option value="Thu"><?php echo $thursday; ?></option>
<option value="Fri"><?php echo $friday; ?></option>
</select>
</form>
```

I've tried several jquery tutorials on submitting forms without a refresh, but they all involve a submit button. I need one that binds the submitting of the form to when a choice is selected in the dropdown.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Solved
Using some of the ideas from the answers here, some tutorials, and a lot of trial/error. I finally got it figure out. Here is the code that works

```
$('#day').change(function() 
{
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "tutoringlistsession.php",
        data: $("form.day").serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $('#list').load('tutoringlist.php', function(){
            });
            $('#list').show("fast");
        }
    });
                return false;
});
```

Comment: this.form.submit() acts like a submit button as far as I know

Comment: taking a submit without refresh tutorial and changing it to do so on select shouldn't be much of a stretch , show us what you have tried

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below.  It's perfectly fine to "accept" your own answer.  This way, the question gets 'closed out'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the ideas posted in here and several tutorials to figure out the answer. The working code is below:

```
$('#day').change(function() 
{
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "tutoringlistsession.php",
        data: $("form.day").serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $('#list').load('tutoringlist.php', function(){
            });
            $('#list').show("fast");
        }
    });
                return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind to the form's submit event:

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
   //prevent form submission / page refresh
   e.preventDefault();

   //submit form with ajax
   $.get(window.location, $(this).serialize());
});
```

I would also bind to the `select` with jQuery as well for cleanliness/consistency:

```
$("form select").on('change', function () {
   $("form").trigger('submit');
});
```

I would also use more specific selectors, which requires updating your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Submit form via ajax onChange of the select element:

```
$("select").on('change', function () {
    var thisForm = $(this).closest('form');
    $.get($thisForm.attr('action'), $thisForm.serialize());
});
```