# Using PHP Code without page reload (forms)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use this code for my woocommerce shop so the taxes won't show if the shipping country switzerland is selected. The problem is, that it only works on a page reload.. if the user selects switzerland in the form it does not change immediately.. is there a way it constantly checks if the country is ch?

```
<?php  global $woocommerce;
$county     = array('CH');

if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) :
    echo "<style> .order-tax {display:none;} </style>";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to use JQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939794/submit-form-without-refresh-after-selection-from-dropdown you use  ajax to call a php page to do the processing

Comment: No I haven't since I am kind of a newbe... Can you give me a hint/code?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery for that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#billing_country').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'CH')
            $('.order-tax').css('display', 'none');
        else    
            $('.order-tax').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using <script> tag if that is in php file?

Comment: no it is a html file.. it just doesn't get the billing form correctly. it works in a fiddle though